# Ruby where column is alphanumeric

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a table of cards. I would like to do a query that filters the elements to those with a title that has English alphanumeric characters, i.e. A-Z or 0-9.

How would I go about doing this?

I tried `Card.where(title: )`. The problem is that this only appears to do direct comparisons. I believe I need to apply some regex parameter. Is this possible?

Similarly, is there an easy way to pass a method to the `where` function with which I can do all the logic, such as `Card.where(title: myCheckerMethod)`?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: You can not pass ruby method to database, instead you can get all records and filter them by your method, but it would be not efficient

Comment: postgresql i think, on heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using PostgreSQL, your where statement can supply a pattern to match with.  However, it should be noted that this effectively removes the database agnostic style of rails, and you'll have to use the regex syntax specific to the database type that is used.

`Card.where('cards.title ~* ?', '[A-Z0-9]+')`